# Batch Rename Folders Recursively

Tags: windows, batch-file, rename, directory

Here's the current file structure: a heading folder, a person folder, and then a set of files pertaining to that person. For example, here are just the FOLDERS. Oh, BTW, obviously I'm not spending days processing data on cartoon characters; these are just illustrative to hopefully make understanding easier.

```
The Simpsons
  Homer Simpson
    Homer Simpson - At the Plant
    Homer Simpson - At Duffs Bar
    Homer Simpson - On a Date with Marge
  Bart Simpson
    Bart Simpson - Bart Writing on the Chalkboard
    Bart Simpson - Playing with Millhouse
    Bart Simpson - Earns Money for Camp Krusty
    Bart Simpson - Sings with Lisa
  Etc...
```

and because having the name repeated is so redundant on a large scale, I've been trying to just make:

```
The Simpsons
  Homer Simpson
    At the Plant
    At Duffs Bar
    On a Date with Marge
  Bart Simpson
    Bart Writing on the Chalkboard
    Playing with Millhouse
    Earns Money for Camp Krusty
    Sings with Lisa
  Etc...
```

Basically, I've been manually stripping the

```
<artist name><space><dash><space>
```

from the "base" of each child folder underneath each person. all manually from literally a thousand folders in Windows File Explorer today and trying to research/try different batch files to just do the rename programmatically. I have thousands to go, so I thought I'd ask for help.

I know StackOverflow is NOT a file writing service and it's insulting for others to think they can get someone else to do their work. I totally get it.

I have a dozen or so things that I 'think' should work, but they don't.
I started to list code I've tried but I think this would be more succinct:

```
for recursive directories tokens=3 delims=dash %%<some variable> in (*. ) do rename <filename element 1><space><dash><space><filename element 2> with <filename element2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't used to answer this type of questions, but your request seems funny to me, so here it is!

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Enter to "heading" folder
cd "The Simspons"

rem Process all "person" folders here
for /D %%a in (*) do (

   rem Enter to this "person" folder
   cd "%%a"

   rem Rename all folders here, as requested
   for /F "delims=" %%b in ('dir /B /A:D') do (
      set "folder=%%b"

      rem For new name: remove all characters from beginning until " - "
      ren "%%b" "!folder:* - =!"
   )

   rem Go back to the "heading" folder
   cd ..

)
```

This program fail if the names of the folders may include an exclamation mark `!` character.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and for putting work into helping solving this! I tested and the routine won't cd into the person's directory (Homer or Bart). You can test by putting a dummy txt at the 'current' folder (where the bat resides) then try copying it to the person's dir. I put "somefile.txt" where the bat lives, then edited your code to say:

   rem Enter to this "person" folder
   cd "%%a"
   copy "f:\sandbox\somefile.txt"
   
   ) then ended the for loop here and temporarily deleted the rest to just test out the CD behavior.

Comment: BTW, i read through your file word by word and to a human the logic looks good and reads very logically, but somewhere the syntax is off...that's the trouble with batch files...they are so non-intuitive. I can't see how this scenario (stripping elements from a folder name) isn't something that hasn't been covered a billion times since 1990. I could also make an input file via: cmd, cd, then dir *. /s > somefile.txt then write a macro in a text editor to markup each line w/ the proper rename syntax. Tried this: ren "Homer Simpson - At the Plant" "At the Plant" e.g. for each folder, but no go...

Comment: Well, you may try to do an effort by yourself to find the problem. For example, you could remove the `@echo off` line, so you can see in the screen the execution of commands, or you may insert `echo` commands at several places in the program, so you can see the values of the variables, etc. You said: _"it's insulting for others to think they can get someone else to do their work"_... **`:/`**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is still looking for this, and I was not able to comment on the above answer due to my lack of rep, so I'm hoping I can provide some clarity here.  I've had some success with the following:

Instead of using `ren "%%b" "!folder:* - =!"` you will need to use a varied method to Aacini's version above, utilizing the `move` command instead.

`Ren` or `Rename` will only rename *files* not folders.

Using `Move` you can move a folder as well as change the directory's name in the process.

Borrowing from Aacini's code, you could try something like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Use the following line so you can run this batch file directly from the main dir, I.E.
rem "The Simpsons"
pushd %~dp0

rem Process all "person" folders here
for /D %%a in (*) do (

   rem Set a new variable for the recursive directory searches
   set ndir=%%a

   rem Set a variable to make referencing the future directories easier as well as
   rem entering this "person" folder (you may need to place a "\" between %~dp0 and %ndir%)

   rem As I mention below -- may need a subroutine for this as well.
   set fdir=%~dp0%ndir%
   cd "%fdir%"

   rem Rename all folders here, as requested
   for /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%b in (`dir /B /AD`) do (

      rem For making the New Directory Name, we will need to set %%b to a new 
      rem variable and then call out a 'subroutine' from within the for loop.
      set fnm=%%b

      call :Moverino
   )

rem Failing to call out to a 'subroutine' will kill the variables in my experience.
:Moverino

rem Adding an echo here proves your fnm variable took the filename - not required
echo %fnm%

rem Here you are substituting every character before the ' - ' to equal "nothing"
set fnm1=%fnm:* - =%

rem Adding another echo here to echo the new fnm1 variable - this will prove whether the
rem edit works in strings at all, regardless if it is file vs directory.
echo %fnm1%

rem This timeout was just to check to make sure things worked in debugging
rem The code moves so fast, it's easy to miss what's happening.
REM timeout /t 1

rem Here is the sweet-sauce.  "Ren" or "Rename" will not rename directories, however,
rem Moving directories from one to another as a different name will change the name!
Move "%~dp0%fnm%" "%~dp0%fnm1%"
```

Keep in mind that some things fail terribly in For loops, so if the change directory does not work, you might need to call that out into another subroutine.  If this is the case, you will *need* to setup some kind of checksum to prevent you from utilizing the moving portion of the code too.  This should only change the names of the folders within the directories.

I have not verified whether `:* - =%` will do exactly what you're hoping, but this type of command has not failed me before.

Comment: Another thing that made me sad is that this only went one level deep.  I've worked on trying to go deeper and could partially make a 2nd one work, but it gets ugly.

Comment: Throw a `For /R %%D in (%CD%) do ()` loop around the outside.